# mod_wsgi + python 2.7.5 + Apache 2.4.9 compiled

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

Where can I download mod_wsgi for python 2.7.5 + Apache2.4.9 + windows. I have tried so hard and so many times to compile on my windows, but I always get a lot of errors. is there a link to download it with these specifications, or anyone who has to compile it. I really need it for my server with python 2.7.5 win32. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

At this page: [Click!](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi). It's a good idea to bookmark this page, it contains a lot of unofficial windows binaries for Python.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've tried to download "[mod_wsgi-3.5.ap24.win32-py2.7.zip](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/4y6heurj/mod_wsgi-3.5.ap24.win32-py2.7.zip)", but it build with python 2.7.6, which I need is build with python 2.7.5

Comment: i have tried with "[mod_wsgi-3.5.ap24.win32-py2.7.zip](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/4y6heurj/mod_wsgi-3.5.ap24.win32-py2.7.zip)", which build on python 2.7.6, but i get an error because my python version is 2.7.5.